# How to turn a Sakai instance open access

Tags: java, mysql, maven, plugins, sakai

I am currently working with a **Sakai 11** instance in a project, and I need to somehow "publish" the contents of the CMS to make it an **open access** platform.

Registered users would accept that contents will be publicly accessible (open access) during register. No problem with that.

Is there any easy way to achieve this? Which are the correct steps?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Nobody has a clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To allow users to view or even edit things without logging in, grant those permissions to `.anon`:

1. Log in as admin.
2. Copy the site's ID (part of its URL).
3. Open the *Realms* tool.
4. Open the site's realm. Its name is `/site/` followed by the site ID.
5. Add a new role named `.role`.
6. Give it the permissions you want non-logged-in users to have. (Yes, their names are fairly cryptic and poorly documented. Try them out on a test site.)
7. Log out, or use a different browser, to test.

[These steps are from the Sakai wiki, which has a bit more detail](https://confluence.sakaiproject.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=3440651).

[The University of Oxford uses this for MOOC-like sites.](https://confluence.sakaiproject.org/display/DOC/Role-Based-Access-To-Sites)

This doesn't require any programming, so it's off-topic for this site ...

Comment: Not really exactly what I wanted, but a reasonably acceptable workaround for this issue. Thanks.

Comment: Alternatively, you can make the site joinable and publish a page from which prospective users can register and then self-join. We did this for one of our courses and created a new role for this purpose.